# Laravel: Call to a member function store() on null in file

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I currently have an API where it uploads a PDF to a lesson but I want to make the PDF upload nullable but it returns an error:

> Error: Call to a member function store() on null in file C:\xampp\htdocs\drv-api\app\Http\Controllers\Api\LessonCRUDController.php on line 66

And this is my line 66:

> $uploaded_files = $request->file->store('public/uploads/');

I want to make the PDF file upload nullable. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the uploaded file is valid using `isValid()` method.

```
if($request->file->isValid()){
    $uploaded_files = $request->file->store('public/uploads/');
}
```